# Как вывести дополнительные поля на сайт на Битриксе?

Tags: битрикс, меню, иконки

Добрый вечер,
Сайт сделан на Битриксе , не могли бы вы помочь , как вывести дополнительные поля на сайт.
У меня есть вертикальное меню (каталог), не знаю как добавить там иконки перед ссылкой.
Прикрепляем скриншот.
Спасибо

[image: меню(каталог)]

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы вывести дополнительные иконки, вам нужно изменить шаблон компонента, отвечающего за вывод меню. Чтобы узнать, где лежит шаблон этого компонента, необходимо:

1. Зайти под администратором в публичную часть сайта и включить режим правки:

   [image: рис.1]
2. Далее навести на область меню и выбрать нужный компонент (скорее всего `bitrix:menu`), затем «Редактировать шаблон компонента»:

   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее у вас будет возможность добавить вывод поля, которое есть в `$arResult`.

Comment: <img src="<?=$arResult["UF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE"]["IMG"]?>" border="0" />
 <a
 href="<?=$arResult["ALL_ITEMS"][$itemID]["LINK"]?> "
 
 <?if (is_array($arColumns) && count($arColumns) > 0 && $existPictureDescColomn):?>
  onmouseover="window.obj_<?=$menuBlockId?> && obj_<?=$menuBlockId?>.changeSectionPicure(this, '<?=$itemID?>');"
 <?endif?>
>
 <span>
  <?=$arResult["ALL_ITEMS"][$itemID]["TEXT"]?>
  <?if (is_array($arColumns) && count($arColumns) > 0):?><i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i><?endif?>
 </span>
</a>

Comment: <img src="<?=$arResult["UF_BACKGROUND_IMAGE"]["IMG"]?>" border="0" /> 

Вот это добавил перед ссылкой , но не сработало(

Comment: Отправьте пожалуйста весь код или напишите в скайп pashaflat53

Comment: а вы в телграме есть ?

Comment: да +375298316977

Comment: спасибо за помощь  Smolin Pavel , ваш ответь помочь мне решить проблему